# Pygame simple program to test displaying is freezing

Tags: python, pygame

Could someone with more experience than I give me a clue as to why the following code is freezing (hanging) the window? All it should do it display a red screen and update its FPS in the window name. Thank you! :)

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame import Color


class Game():
    """ Lets try to get this going by simple steps
    One by one. First step, lets figure how to make a class
    that can do the display stuff. Lord have mercy on my soul"""

    runGame = True

    def __init__(self, wi=256, hi=224, multii=3):
        """Initialization"""
        pygame.init()
        self.width      = wi*multii
        self.height     = hi*multii
        self.spritesize = 16*multii
        self.clock      = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.fps        = self.clock.get_fps()
        self.screen     = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))

    def mainLoop(self):
        """Loop through the main game routines
        1. Drawing  2. Input handling  3. Updating
        Then loop through it until user quits"""
        while self.runGame:
            self.clock.tick(12)
            self.draw()
            self.events()

    def events(self):
        """Time to handle some events"""
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            print e
            if (e.type == pygame.QUIT) or 
            (e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE):
                self.runGame = False

    def draw(self):
        """Draw and update the main screen"""
        self.screen.fill(Color('red'))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Grid2. FPS: '+str(self.fps))
        pygame.display.update()


game = Game()
game.mainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the Game class you declare `runGame` outside of the `__init__` function and you don't put `self.runGame` for the deceleration. You also only update the FPS when the Game object is first created, so it will remain at the same value.

Fix this by:

1. Moving the `runGame` deceleration within the initialization code and make it `self.runGame`
2. Add a call to update `self.fps`. I've added it under the `draw` function

So your ending code should look like this (Comments are included where I changed things):

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame import Color


class Game():
    """ Lets try to get this going by simple steps
    One by one. First step, lets figure how to make a class
    that can do the display stuff. Lord have mercy on my soul"""



def __init__(self, wi=256, hi=224, multii=3):
    """Initialization"""
    pygame.init()
    self.width      = wi*multii
    self.height     = hi*multii
    self.spritesize = 16*multii
    self.clock      = pygame.time.Clock()
    self.fps        = self.clock.get_fps()
    self.screen     = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
    self.runGame = True # I've moved the runGame decleration

def mainLoop(self):
    """Loop through the main game routines
    1. Drawing  2. Input handling  3. Updating
    Then loop through it until user quits"""
    while self.runGame:
        self.clock.tick(12)
        self.draw()
        self.event()

def events(self):
    """Time to handle some events"""
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for e in events:
        print e
        if (e.type == pygame.QUIT) or 
        (e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE):
            self.runGame = False


def draw(self):
    """Draw and update the main screen"""
    self.screen.fill(Color('red'))
    self.fps = self.clock.get_fps() # I reupdate the FPS counter
    pygame.display.set_caption('Grid2. FPS: '+str(self.fps))
    pygame.display.update()


game = Game()
game.mainLoop()
```

Comment: I made your edit, and thanks for that, its more consistent that way, but the window is still freezing for me. In that I have to force quit out of it and it wont let me move the window around at all. It just stays frozen.

Comment: That may be because you don't have any event handling, but I'm not 100% on that

Comment: Hmm, that could be it. I'll slap some in and see!... That was it. Thanks DeadChex!

Comment: Let me know how it goes, I'm here to help

Comment: Updated the OP with some event code, works now! Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem, I'll change the answer code to reflect the code change. EDIT: Changed